# Многопоточность C#. Вывод в TextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, многопоточность, текст

Имеется файл, где большое количество строк. Вывод файла осущствляется построчно циклом. Но из-за того, что файл большой, действие идет больше 60 сек и вызывается исключение. Как решить эту проблему?

```
 StreamReader file = new StreamReader("buffer2.txt");
                string line = file.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    textBox3.Text += line + "\r\n";
                    line = file.ReadLine();
                }
```

Comment: Вам действительно нужно выводить огромное количество текста на экран? Кто будет его читать?

Comment: 1. Запускать в отдельном потоке. 2. Писать сначала в переменную, потом только один раз в конце в контрол.

Comment: `textBox3.Text += File.ReadAllLines("buffer2.txt");`

Comment: Неужели у вас возникает OutOfMemoryException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //флаг запуска чтения файла
    private bool _isReading;
    //источник токена отмены
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxFile.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            buttonReadFile.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            textBoxFile.Text = String.Empty;
            buttonReadFile.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private async void buttonReadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //если процесс чтения уже стартовал
        if (_isReading)
        {
            //отменяем чтение файла
            _tokenSource.Cancel();

            return;
        }


        //флаг чтения
        _isReading = true;
        //интерфейс
        buttonReadFile.Text = "Отменить";
        buttonFile.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            //готовим токе отмены
            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = _tokenSource.Token;

            //запускаем чтение, по окончании отображаем результат
            textBoxOutput.Text = await Task.Run(() => ReadFile(textBoxFile.Text, token), token);

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            //чтение было отменено
            textBoxOutput.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка чтения файла",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            _isReading = false;
            _tokenSource.Dispose();

            buttonReadFile.Text = "Прочитать";
            buttonFile.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private string ReadFile(string file, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //для сбора прочитанных строк
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        //для отображения прогресса чтения файла
        Action<string> action = s => textBoxOutput.Text = s;

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                string line = String.Empty;
                int counter = 1;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //выбрасываем исключение в случае отмены
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    //добавляем прочитанную строку
                    result.AppendLine(line);

                    //показываем прогресс чтения
                    var message = $"Читаем файл..., строка: {counter++}";
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                        this.Invoke(action, message);
                    else
                        action(message);
                }
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```